# TV4: to get more details of detected errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, tv4

I am using tv4 to detect schema errors.
I tried getting all results using: `tv4.validateMultiple` call which detected multiple errors but did not say where or why.

Is there any way in tv4 to provide more elaborate information of failures?

```
var res = tv4.validateMultiple(data, schema,null,true);

errors:[]
0:{}
message:"Missing required property: coMMand"
name:"ValidationError"
type:"Error"
1:{}
message:"Unknown property (not in schema)"
name:"ValidationError"
type:"Error"
2:{}
message:"Unknown property (not in schema)"
name:"ValidationError"
type:"Error"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is not possible to do with tv4 and since there is not being any more enhancements to the module. The ajv on the other hand provides better results:

```
var ajv = new Ajv({allErrors: true});
//define some schema
schema = {...};
//validate with some invalid schema
ajv.validate(schema,{s:'a'});
console.log(ajv.errors);
```

Following result is found:

```
dataPath:""
keyword:"additionalProperties"
message:"should NOT have additional properties"
params:{}
additionalProperty:"s"
schemaPath:"#/additionalProperties"
```